# Can I access SimpleXMLElement child with namespace using object notation?

Tags: php, xml

I would like to do something like this on an `SimpleXMLElement`:

```
$el = $xml->{'alias:child'}
```

I don't want to use `children()`, nor `xpath()` and don't want to strip the namespaces upfront.

*NOTE* the prefixes are not defined by contract. However, they can be retrieved upfront using `getNamespaces()` so the right alias for the desired namespace can be used.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe it isn't possible. The rationale is that prefix is not contractual and can change any time.

Comment: I've updated how I obtain the namespace prefixes. That should always work and be more stable that reg-exing. Downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote. In fact the question is more interesting that it seems at first sight. But I guess whoever wrote the tool never considered such interface.

Comment: Any particular reason for not wanting to use `children()`?  Another solution would be to use DOMDocument and `getElementsByTagName()`

Comment: I have xml that uses different namespaces at different nesting levels. Using `children($ns,true)` at a higher level seems to remove all *other* namespaces even from grandchildren.